# Division result is 0

Tags: excel, vba

It might look stupid but as I divide 11950 by 47086514 the result is 0.

This is what I tried:

```
Dim total, share As Long
Dim split1 As Variant
split1 = Array(size1)

For i = 1 To size1 - 6
    split1 = Split(vetA(i), ":") 'vetA(1) = 11950 and total = 47086514
    share = CLng(split1(1)) / total
    ws.Cells(i + 4, 16).Value = share
Next i
```

Comment: Total and Share should be Doubles not Longs: `Dim Total as Double, Share as Double`.  Longs are integer values only no decimal.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure you don't want to be `split`ting inside a `for` loop

Comment: Please also note that if you `Dim total, share As Long` only `share` is of type `Long` but `total` is of type `Variant` you need to specify a type for **every** variable in VBA or it is `Variant` by default: `Dim Total as Double, Share as Double`. I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. And also use meaningful variable names. If you need to number variable names `split1` then you did something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation about Scott Craner comment above:
`Double` (and `Float`) has a decimal point. `Long` doesn't. `Long` is simply a bigger `Integer`.

So if I take `A/B` and `A = 1` and `B = 2` and define both `A`, `B` as `Long` then the result would be `0`.

If I define `A`, `B` as `Decimal` then the answer would be `0.5` (as you'd think). 
This behaviour exists across programming languages which are typed, once you define a type (as you've done above) and it's by design. Some things (humans, cars) don't convey a real meaning beyond the decimal point (what does it mean to have `2.4` kids per family?).

When in doubt, always check the data types available in the programming language you're using. You'd be surprised where [this discussion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/) might take you.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me